# jpa UnsupportedOperationException: query result offset is not supported

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am use `spring boot` + `jpa` to access data from db. Database is `sqlserver`.

spring boot version: 1.4.1
hibernate version:5.0.11

When I use `findAll(pageable)` to list data, I received this exception:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: query result offset is not supported`

Here is my repository:

```
package com.my.home.dao;

import com.didi.home.model.DdForumArticle;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 * Created by jacks808@163.com on 2017/1/13.
 */
public interface DdForumArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<DdForumArticle, Integer> {
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
import com.didi.home.model.DdForumArticle;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jacks808@163.com on 2017/1/13.
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class DdForumArticleRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    DdForumArticleRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void findOrderByArticleId() throws Exception {
        Page<DdForumArticle> articlePage = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 2, Sort.Direction.DESC, "articleId"));
        System.out.println(articlePage.getTotalPages());
    }
}
```

Here is the exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: query result offset is not supported

    at org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.TopLimitHandler.processSql(TopLimitHandler.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:586)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:406)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:375)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.didi.home.dao.DdForumArticleRepositoryTest.findOrderByArticleId(DdForumArticleRepositoryTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Is there some wrong usage in my code?

BTW, I can access data by `findOne` method.

Comment: FWIW This is Spring Data JPA API (which is NOT the JPA API). Your real JPQL query is not shown, so you have to debug what is being passed to your JPA provider by Spring

Comment: What is you SQL Server version and what hibernate dialect you use? It seems like you are using `SQLServer2012Dialect` and SQL Server pre 2012.

Answer (score 25):

I'm answering here just because a lot of people would not check comments. **#Robert Niestroj already answer this in above comments.**

Use This (for MS SQL server 2008 and onward)
    org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

And org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect only for 2000 and 2005.

Comment: Wow was not expecting a winner...   but yes, its fixed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

use `legacy_limit_handler` to have a try.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.legacy_limit_handler=true
```

works for me.

Comment: It works for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

I changed dialect in hiberante.cfg.xml file,

replace it

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

by it

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
```

Comment: This was the one for me. SQLServerDialect has supportsLimitOffset set to false, which was causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

Using 2016 Dialect fixed the issue for me.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2016Dialect
```

Comment: This works for me too on non spring project

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code issue will be resolved.

'Use This (for MS SQL server 2008 and onward) org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect'

Comment: Please add in your configuration and tell me if issue resolved.

Comment: How does the guidance in this answer differ from the guidance in the answers already posted here?